# Sort points in clockwise order

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm trying to sort a List of (x,y) points in clockwise order. I was trying to implement in Python algorithm from this site  https://www.baeldung.com/cs/sort-points-clockwise, but I don't really understand how sort function was used with function as an argument. I tried to use sorted() Python function, but it didn't work out. Can someone give me some tips how can I achieve this in Python?

[part of sort clockwise algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekcHS.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, you can't pass `sorted` (or `sort`) a direct comparison function that compares two values, but you can pass a `key` function that transforms a single value into one that can be compared using regular numeric or string comparison to get your desired result. In this case, for instance, you could write a function that would take a point and return the angle to it:

```
import math
def angle_to(point):
  # assumes already mapped to (0,0) center
  # modify as needed to get result in desired range
  return math.atan2(point[1],point[0])
```

And then sort the list like so:

```
# reverse=True for clockwise, since conventional math angles increase
# going counter-clockwise
sorted_points = sorted(points_list, key=angle_to, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Now it is quite obvious. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The algorithm outlined on that site is easy enough to implement:

```
import math
import statistics
import random

# Generate random points – the parameters to random.uniform are chosen arbitrarily,
# but we just want to make sure we need to do some work at centering the points.
points = [(random.uniform(3, 10), random.uniform(-11, 1)) for x in range(10)]

# Use the "zip splat" trick to transpose the list of 2-tuple coordinates into 2 tuples
xs, ys = zip(*points)

# Get the average of the points as an estimate of the center
x_center = statistics.mean(xs)
y_center = statistics.mean(ys)


# Define a sorting function:
def sort_pt(point):
    # Destructure the point to x and y
    x, y = point

    # Translate the points according to the estimated center
    x -= x_center
    y -= y_center

    # Get the angle of this point from the estimated center
    angle = math.atan2(y, x)

    # Get the distance squared of this point from the estimated center
    dist = (x ** 2) + (y ** 2)

    # Return a 2-tuple; Python will use the values in order for sorting.
    # This means that things are primarily sorted by angle, and in case of a tie
    # (which is unlikely if the coordinates are not integer), the distance.
    # We reverse the angle here since `atan2` returns counter-clockwise coordinates;
    # using `reverse` in `sorted()` would also reverse the `dist` factor.
    return (-angle, dist)


# Sort the points using `sorted` using the above function as a key.
sorted_points = sorted(
    points,
    key=sort_pt,
)

print(points)
print(sorted_points)
```